# simple-rss gem taking ages to parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, process, rss

im parsing some rss using 'simple-rss' gem. The feed is big and heavy but i still wonder if im doing something wrong because the process seems endless.

Im using delayed_job to run the process in background. Here´s the controller:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  require 'open-uri'

  FEED_URI = 'http://rss....'

  def get_feed
    Delayed::Job.enqueue FeedJob.new(FEED_URI)
    @events = Event.all
  end

end
```

Then comes to this Class:

```
class FeedJob < Struct.new(:uri)

  require 'rubygems'
  require 'simple-rss'
  require 'open-uri'

  def perform
    entryAttr = Event::TAGS + Session::TAGS + Venue::TAGS     #IM ADDING AROUND 30 TAGS
    SimpleRSS.item_tags += entryAttr                              #HERE
    rss = SimpleRSS.parse open(uri)
    rss.entries.each do |entry|
      venue = Venue.find_by_map_number(entry.venueMapNumber) || Venue.new
      save_venue(venue,entry)
      event = Event.find_by_guid(entry.eventGuid) || Event.new
      save_event(event,entry,venue)
      session = Session.find_by_guid(entry.sessionGuid) || Session.new
      save_session(session,entry,event)
    end
  end
end
```

Any insight would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `SimpleRSS` is where things are slowing down?

You are doing a lot of database reads and writes for each entry. Have you tried taking those out to see how fast `SimpleRSS` really is? I suspect your database is the real bottleneck.

If the database is the cause, there are things you can do to speed it up.

First, check out the your log file and see which queries are slowest. Fix the slow ones.

- For reads, you should make sure they are hitting indexes. For this query to be performant, your `venues` table should have an indexed on `map_number`:

  ```
  Venue.find_by_map_number(entry.venueMapNumber)
  ```
- For writes, you can batch up your writes into transactions so you don't have a whole transaction for every `save`. This has to be done delicately as you don't want your transactions to be too big either. I usually try to cap transactions to 1-3k inserts/updates. At the very least, wrap your three saves in a transaction:

  ```
  rss.entries.each do |entry|
    venue = Venue.find_by_map_number(entry.venueMapNumber) || Venue.new
    event = Event.find_by_guid(entry.eventGuid) || Event.new
    session = Session.find_by_guid(entry.sessionGuid) || Session.new
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      save_venue(venue,entry)
      save_event(event,entry,venue)
      save_session(session,entry,event)
    end
  end
  ```

Comment: That some good info Carl, thanks. But in this case it never even gets into that "entries.each" loop. So yes, i would say is SimpleRSS what´s taking so long (and i suspect it might be because it has so many custon tags)

Comment: Interesting. I'm not too familiar with SimpleRSS. How big is the rss feed? Lots of XML libs start to choke on big files as they cause the library to allocate tons of objects and possibly run your system out of memory. You might need to look at using an evented XML parser, like `Nokogiri::XML::SAX`. It could of course be the tags as you mentioned. Best way to know for sure is profile your code using a [profiler](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof) and see which method calls are taking the most time, and investigate from there.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the parsing is actually what's slow or could it be the HTTP fetching?